# Cordova/Ionic framework, send/share audio file thru whatsapp

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm new with Cordova/Ionic, I've managed to reproduce mp3 files with my app using NativeAudio plugin wrapped with ng-cordova.
I have CordovaSocial plugin installed, but I can't figure out how to send audio file to whatsapp.
the mp3 is in www/audio/bass.mp3

With these lines I can reproduce the mpfile

```
$scope.play = function(audioFile) {
$cordovaNativeAudio.preloadSimple(audioFile, 'audio/' + audioFile + '.mp3');

$cordovaNativeAudio.play(audioFile);
}
```

Here my code

in html file something like

```
<div class="buttons" ng-click="shareViaWhatsApp(null,null,'audio/bass.mp3')">
    <button class="button">Whatsapp</button>
</div>
```

and in the js file

```
$scope.shareViaWhatsApp = function(message, image, link) {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("whatsapp", message, image, link).then(function(result) {
  $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(message, image, link);
  //$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp('test message', null, null); //this works

}, function(error) {
  alert("Cannot share on WhatsApp " + error);
});
```

I get URL_NOT_SUPPORTED when trying to send mp3 file thru whatsapp

Comment: Are you using this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Yes, I'm using ng-Cordova plugin that wraps the plugin you mention.
https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/socialSharing.js

Comment: How are you passing the file? the url?

Comment: Try first using 'www/audio/bass.mp3' and check this issue: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/394

Comment: you got it working?